# GNU Octave - base64_decode / base64_encode

Tags: java, base64, octave

i have the following problem:
Inside of a java program i encode a string to the base64 format:

```
package my;

import java.util.Base64;

public class base64 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // check for an input
        if(args.length > 0)
        {
            Base64.Encoder encoder = java.util.Base64.getEncoder();

            for(int i = 0; i< args.length; ++i)
            {
                String encoded = encoder.encodeToString(args[i].getBytes());
                System.out.println(encoded);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The string ...

```
firstname lastname<$!$>email@domain.tld<$!$>message
```

... results in :

```
Zmlyc3RuYW1lIGxhc3RuYW1lPCQhJD5lbWFpbEBkb21haW4udGxkPCQhJD5tZXNzYWdl
```

This seems to work fine. But if i want to decode this base64-string back to a normal string in GNU Octave with the following program:

```
b64encoded = "Zmlyc3RuYW1lIGxhc3RuYW1lPCQhJD5lbWFpbEBkb21haW4udGxkPCQhJD5tZXNzYWdl";
decoded = base64_decode(b64encoded);

%output the type and the string
disp(typeinfo(decoded));
disp(["decoded : " decoded]);
```

... i'm ending up with one of the following error messages every time.

```
error: base64_decode: incorrect input size
```

or

```
error: base64_decode: input was not valid base64
```

As this was not working i tried to encode a given string with Octave, but this doesn't work because i don't understand how to transform a string to the array-type which base64_encode wants to have as an input. After that i googled around for 2 days, reading lots of posts, the docu and also tried to understand the underlying c implementation of Octaves base64_encode and base64_decode but this also doesn't helped me.

So my main questions are:

1. What is my misstake with octaves decode function?
2. How do i encode anoctave string to base64?

Thanks in advance,

nioerd

Comment: The result of the Java base64 encoder is just fine, you can check at https://www.base64decode.org/ (and https://www.base64encode.org/) So your question is really not about Java, but only about Gnu Octave

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation shows, the Octave function `base64_decode` is not a general-purpose base64 decoder function, but rather a function that returns an array of doubles that were encoded as binary:

> Built-in Function: x = base64_decode (s)
>
> Decode the **double** matrix or array x from the base64 encoded string s.

You can see the same in the source code of GNU Octave:

```
56 Array<double>
57 octave_base64_decode (const std::string& str)
```

And the "incorrect input size" error is because your string is not a multiple of the size of a double (typically 8 bytes) long:

```
76       if ((outlen % (sizeof (double) / sizeof (char))) != 0)
77         {
78           ::free (out);
79           (*current_liboctave_error_handler)
80             ("base64_decode: incorrect input size");
81         }
```

That's your question 1: what you're doing wrong is, the `base64_decode` function is not meant to decode strings, but only to decode binary doubles.

Your question 2: the extension package `strings` provides functions `base64encode` and `base64decode` (without underscores) that *do* encode/decode strings:

http://octave.sourceforge.net/strings/

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've tried the strings extension from octave forge and run instantly into the next hole.

The base64decode function can only decode to ASCII, but i need UTF-8.

Did you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function r=isOctave()
    a=ver;
    a=a(1).Name;
    r=isequal(a,'Octave');
end

function r=base64decode8(d)
    if isOctave
        r=typecast(base64_decode(d),'char');
    else
        r=char(matlab.net.base64decode(d));
    end
    r=r(r>0);
end

function r=base64encode8(d)
    d=[d,repmat(char(0),1,7-mod(length(d)-1,8))]; % add zero characters to expand length to factor of 8
    if isOctave
        r=base64_encode(uint8(d));
    else
        r=matlab.net.base64encode(uint8(d));
    end
end
```